# Java stripping zeros from function

Tags: java, byte, bitmask, fold

I'm trying to flip some bytes around in Java and the function I have is working correctly for some bytes and failing for others.

The function I am using is this:

```
public static int foldInByte(int m, int pos, byte b) {
    int tempInt = (b << (pos * 8));
    tempInt = tempInt & (0x000000ff << (pos * 8));
    m = m | tempInt;
    return m;
}
```

And the code that implements this is:

```
byte[] bitMaskArray = new byte[]{
                            byteBuffer.get(inputIndex),
                            byteBuffer.get(inputIndex + 1),
                            byteBuffer.get(inputIndex + 2),
                            byteBuffer.get(inputIndex + 3)};
                        int tempInt = 0;

                        tempInt = foldInByte(0, 3, bitMaskArray[3]);
                        tempInt = foldInByte(tempInt, 2, bitMaskArray[2]);
                        tempInt = foldInByte(tempInt, 1, bitMaskArray[1]);
                        tempInt = foldInByte(tempInt, 0, bitMaskArray[0]);

                        bitMask = tempInt;
```

The bytes are being read from a ByteBuffer with the byteOrder being Little Endian.

For example, the bytes 00 01 B6 02 set the bitMask to: 2B60100 - which works perfectly in my program.

However, if the bytes are A0 01 30 00, the bitMask is set to: 3001A0  - which has stipped the last zero from the bitmask.

Is there any way I can stop Java from stipping off trailing zeros?

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Tony

Comment: What do you mean by "stripping"? In the first case one zero is "stripped" too (2B60100 instead of 02B60100), but the truth is that in both cases leading (insignificant) zeroes simply aren't printed when you output a mask. Internally it's still a 32 bit integer with all leading zeros. Or do I misunderstand your question completely? By the way, what's the point of the second line in foldInByte()?

Comment: If I'm brutally honest I don't really understand how the function works.

I'm trying to rearrange bytes in Java so that they read a certain way as an unsigned int and I've been told this is one way of doing it.

When I say stripping zeros I mean that there isn't a zero at the end of the number which I need as I'm using it as a binary bitmask/bit array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zeros are not being stripped -- both examples cited are correct.

- 00 01 B6 02 is the 4-byte little-endian for 2B60100
- A0 01 30 00 is the 4-byte little-endian for 3001A0

The zeros are there, but probably just not being printed.  The System.out.print family of calls will not print leading zero digits.

I might mention that your method is needlessly complex.  Here is a single method that computes the same value:

```
static int extractLittleEndian4(byte[] buf, int index)
{
    int a = buf[index+0]&0xff, b = buf[index+1]&0xff, c = buf[index+2]&0xff, d = buf[index+3]&0xff;
    return a | (b << 8) | (c << 16) | (d << 24);
}
```

Comment: I'd just do `byteBuffer.order(ByteBuffer.LITTLE_ENDIAN); int mask = byteBuffer.getInt();`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a ByteBuffer filled with your bytes already.  Why don't you let the ByteBuffer reverse the bytes for you?  Just add the bytes to the buffer (BIG_ENDIAN is the default if you want to add an integer instead of bytes) and then change the order before reading the integer.

```
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
int output = byteBuffer.getInt(0);
```

If all you're doing is reversing the byte order, let the library do the work for you.  If you happened to start with an integer value, you can even just do this:

```
int input = ...;
int output = Integer.reverseBytes(input);
```